# On premise azure Devops server 2019 Migration to azure devops services without Migration tool

Tags: migration, manual, azure-devops-server-2019

Found from migration options [doc](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/migrate/migrate-from-tfs?view=azure-devops) that manual migration is possible  .But for azure Devops server 2019 pipelines and history migrate to azure Devops services? is there any tools to do that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> for azure Devops server 2019 pipelines and history migrate to azure Devops services? is there any tools to do that?

You could try to use the Azure devops extension [Migration Tools for Azure DevOps](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=nkdagility.vsts-sync-migration), which allow you to migrate Teams, Work Items, and Plans & Suits from one Project to another in Azure DevOps/TFS both within the same Organization, and between Organizations. But this without history and This tool is complicated and its not always easy to discover what you need to do.

If you insist on keeping the history, you could also try to use the 3rd tool [OpsHub Visual Studio Online Migration Utility](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=vs-publisher-1455028.OpsHubVisualStudioOnlineMigrationUtility). It migrates historical information for work items, version control change sets, test cases, test results, and all the relationships between two tools in an incremental manner.

Note: No matter which tool is used, or manual migration, we may not be able to get results were not a perfect copy, but overall the results were actable.